# Не получается натягнуть маску на input

Tags: html, jquery, layout, input, nuget

Проблема в том, что элемент input создается динамически, а именно при нажатии на элемент

```
<div class="own_btn cursor" id="btn_vacday"> <span> Праздничный день </span> </div>
```

При нажатии срабатывает такая часть jQuery

```
$("#btn_vacday").on('click', function () {
        // Проверка на существование элемента. Если нету, то создаем!
        if (!$("div").is("#container_vacday")) {
            $("<div id='container_vacday'></div>").insertAfter("#btn_vacday");

            // Отрисуем форму-контейнер
            design("#container_vacday");

            $("<span> Дата праздника </span><br />").appendTo("#container_vacday");
            $("<input id='date_vacday' type='text' />").appendTo("#container_vacday");


            $("<br /><br /> <textarea id='description_vacday' name='description' placeholder='Описание'  />").appendTo("#container_vacday");
            $("#description_vacday").css({
                height: '75px',
                width: $("#container_vacday").find("input[id^='date_']").width() + 'px'
            });

            $("<br /><br /><input id='cancel_vacday' type='button' value='Отменить'  />").appendTo("#container_vacday");
            $("<input id='submit_vacday' type='submit' value='Отправить' />").appendTo("#container_vacday");
```

Тут еще нету макета. Макет должен появится тут:

```
$("div[id^='btn_']").on('click', function () {
    $("#container_vacday").find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).inputmask("yyyy-mm-dd");
    });
});
```

Но, проблема в том, что макет не налазит на инпут. Хотя в each заходит. Если повесить в each какой-то проверочный alert, то все работает. Например

```
$("#container_vacday").find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
             alert('Here');
         }
    });
```

То выводит Here, но сразу после того, как я еще раз кликну на

```
<div class="own_btn cursor" id="btn_vacday"> <span> Праздничный день </span> </div>
```

Подключаю я jquery.inputmask в пакетах который предлагается пакетами NuGet.

Заранее благодарю за помощь. И не ругайте сильно, ведь я только учусь

Проблема, скорее всего, еще и в том, что впервый раз по событию click не видит никаких потомков, а если еще раз кликнуть на кнопку (div), то тогда что-то срабатывает. Но это все равно не решает проблему с маской

Answer (score 1):

Думаю в данном случае прикрутить маску на момент создания объекта:

```
$("<input id='date_vacday' type='text' />").inputmask("yyyy-mm-dd").appendTo("#container_vacday");
```